# Genre-mash up battle game

Tags: identify-this-game

I am trying to find a game that I had a starter set to when I was younger. I tried doing some online research, but honestly, I don't even know where to start and I can't find anything for it at my local comic/board game shop. I think that it was named something-"scape". I believe that I bought it sometime between 2003 and 2007, but my memory could be a little hazy on that that.

**The Board**

The board was different every time you played because it was made up of a bunch of chunks of hexagons (like honeycombs) that you could put together any way you want. You could even stack them on each other to create different levels. The hexa-combs were made out of plastic and I think they kinda clicked together.

**Gameplay**

*Disclaimer: I was a kid when I played so I could have been disregarding any number of rules and not playing correctly at all, so take this with a grain of salt.*
You controlled a few different heroes and/or monsters (I remember a dragon that took up 2 spaces and I think an archer of some sort?). You moved around the terrain you built and did battle with the enemies heroes/mosters. I do not recall if it was a dice-based game or not. I think each character has a stats card. Unfortunately, I don't remember much about how it was actually played.

**Expansion Sets**

As I said, I think I had a starter set, which seemed to be generic-fantasy themed, but I think there were other sets that could be bought that had heroes/monsters from lots of other genres and more hexagons so that you could wind up with a huge battle with tons of genres mixing it up.

Can anyone point me to this game?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The game is called [Heroscape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heroscape). It was primarily fantasy based, but there were some other expansions like a Marvel themed one. The game was discontinued in 2010 but Wizards of the Coast has recently created a Magic: the Gathering board game called Arena of the Planeswalkers that seems to have similar gameplay.

Comment: Bah, beat me by mere seconds

Comment: Yup! This is it! Thank you so much! Out of curiosity, have you ever played it? Is it any good?

Comment: @Pants I haven't played it myself, but I have heard good things about it. I have played Arena of the Planeswalkers once or twice and enjoyed that.

Comment: @Diego Coolcoolcool. Thank you so much for your super speedy response. I'm gonna have to look into picking up some sets.